# If you click on any square, an X should show up in it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I found the below tutorial for react.
  https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html
- I am trying to achieve this step **If you click on any square, an X should show up in it.**
- but I am not able to achieve it.
- i am not seeing any error.
- can you tell us why its happening
  https://codepen.io/texirv/pen/qmLVOZ?editors=0010

providing code below

```or-tag-here
render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}>
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Because you put `onclick` instead of `onClick` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CodePen appears to use `onclick` instead of `onClick`. React requires `onClick`.